# My MacBook Pro keeps disconnecting from a working wifi network. Genius can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Tags: terminal, network, wifi, airport, internet

The wifi is fine. My MacBook just disconnects. As soon as I click back on the network, it immediately connects again. It is just disconnecting from the network.

- I have disconnected every peripheral, even my mouse and backup external HD, which honestly I need, so any solution will have to include them working. But I have tried just to see if they were involved.
- I have restarted the computer and the modem, there is no router.
- I have reset NVRAM/PRAM and the SMC controller multiple times.
- I have created new locations for Home and School and renewed DCHP Lease for both.
- My OS is updated (Mojave 10.14.6)
- Again, there is nothing wrong with the wifi. Four other people live here and they have no trouble, even those whose computers are located just as far away from the modem as me. It's same floor, down a hall. There are no issues with speed or anything except these random disconnections.
- I have done wifi logging and diagnostics. Please let me know which reports or parts of reports are useful.

These are my settings:

[image: my settings]

This is a list of disconnection events on my wifi in the last 24 hours (tried to do it in image format, but the screenshot was too big apparently):

> 2019-08-09 18:54:10.653502-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 6 (Frame received
>   from nonauthenticated STA).
>
> 2019-08-09 18:54:14.268244-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 8 (Disassociated
>   because station leaving).
>
> 2019-08-09 19:02:52.111634-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-09 20:25:01.808994-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-09 20:55:02.265502-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 6 (Frame received
>   from nonauthenticated STA).
>
> 2019-08-09 20:55:56.187016-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-09 21:33:37.808969-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-09 22:02:34.854710-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 6 (Frame received
>   from nonauthenticated STA).
>
> 2019-08-09 22:03:28.728871-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-09 22:56:09.526982-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 6 (Frame received
>   from nonauthenticated STA).
>
> 2019-08-09 22:57:12.940143-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-09 23:16:25.570955-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 00:01:26.098067-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 6 (Frame received
>   from nonauthenticated STA).
>
> 2019-08-10 00:02:19.727661-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 00:37:37.252461-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 00:56:44.773547-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 6 (Frame received
>   from nonauthenticated STA).
>
> 2019-08-10 00:57:48.114111-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 01:18:49.389065-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 01:30:04.655813-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 01:57:01.203483-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 8 (Disassociated
>   because station leaving).
>
> 2019-08-10 01:59:37.627172-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 02:30:36.197289-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 02:56:05.772928-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 02:57:42.314702-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 6 (Frame received
>   from nonauthenticated STA).
>
> 2019-08-10 02:58:36.249183-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 03:57:52.606604-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 6 (Frame received
>   from nonauthenticated STA).
>
> 2019-08-10 03:57:58.402382-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 6 (Frame received
>   from nonauthenticated STA).
>
> 2019-08-10 03:59:53.741972-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 04:59:54.214106-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 6 (Frame received
>   from nonauthenticated STA).
>
> 2019-08-10 05:00:48.135057-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 06:00:18.844554-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 6 (Frame received
>   from nonauthenticated STA).
>
> 2019-08-10 06:01:22.258747-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 07:01:22.733208-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 6 (Frame received
>   from nonauthenticated STA).
>
> 2019-08-10 07:02:16.651537-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 07:59:54.934698-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 6 (Frame received
>   from nonauthenticated STA).
>
> 2019-08-10 08:00:58.304703-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 08:59:57.062214-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 6 (Frame received
>   from nonauthenticated STA).
>
> 2019-08-10 09:00:05.041950-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 8 (Disassociated
>   because station leaving).
>
> 2019-08-10 09:00:47.001556-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 10:00:29.660375-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 6 (Frame received
>   from nonauthenticated STA).
>
> 2019-08-10 10:22:17.436393-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 11:02:01.906308-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 6 (Frame received
>   from nonauthenticated STA).
>
> 2019-08-10 11:02:55.824622-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 12:01:09.707072-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 8 (Disassociated
>   because station leaving).
>
> 2019-08-10 13:01:45.727945-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 6 (Frame received
>   from nonauthenticated STA).
>
> 2019-08-10 13:01:49.368206-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 8 (Disassociated
>   because station leaving).
>
> 2019-08-10 14:02:07.921087-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 8 (Disassociated
>   because station leaving).
>
> 2019-08-10 14:29:55.682541-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 14:29:55.718300-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 14:34:20.589504-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 15:02:41.688461-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 6 (Frame received
>   from nonauthenticated STA).
>
> 2019-08-10 15:02:43.253119-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 6 (Frame received
>   from nonauthenticated STA).
>
> 2019-08-10 15:53:54.460839-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 16:04:14.709611-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 6 (Frame received
>   from nonauthenticated STA).
>
> 2019-08-10 16:04:51.520036-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
>
> 2019-08-10 17:03:30.375916-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 6 (Frame received
>   from nonauthenticated STA).
>
> 2019-08-10 17:03:39.831849-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 6 (Frame received
>   from nonauthenticated STA).
>
> 2019-08-10 18:03:53.409526-0500  localhost kernel[0]:
>   (IO80211FamilyV2) AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 8 (Disassociated
>   because station leaving).

Like I said, forums, google, reddit, and even the genius who I was on the phone with for over an hour are stumped. Can anyone help a guy out?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) You do mention creating new locations for home and school, but can I ask you to clarify whether this is a problem just at one location,  both of those locations, or when connected to any Wi-Fi network?

Comment: Unfortunately, it being summer, I haven’t been on my school’s network since May. I did not notice any issues then, with this same computer. But nor was this happening on my home network at that point. I have been living in a new place (with a pre-existing wifi that my landlord provides) for about 2 weeks. I only did that because it was a recommended fix that was on Apple’s forums. Not really even sure what the point of Locations is, as I don’t seem to be able to adjust any settings independently based on which one I have selected.

Answer (score 4):

Troubleshooting often involves a process of elimination and can require a lot of patience.

Unfortunately, when it comes to Wi-Fi connection issues there are actually a lot of variables at play, so the best place to start would be to test for whether this is a problem with your MacBook or something specific to the Wi-Fi network. (I know you say there is nothing wrong with the Wi-Fi because others stay connected, but that doesn't actually mean it's not something to do with the Wi-Fi network).

I also know you said there's no router, but the modem will have a built-in router so it's also possible to be something within its settings that are causing a problem.

I would do the following:

**1. Test your MacBook on another Wi-Fi network**

This is a simple test, and a good one to do next if you can, as all you have to do is go somewhere else and connect to Wi-Fi (e.g. a cafe, a friend's place, etc). Once connected, use the MacBook for long enough to establish if you have the same problem.

By doing this, we can establish very quickly whether it's an issue on the MacBook end. If you can stay connected just fine, then we know we have to investigate your usual Wi-Fi network and its environment to pinpoint the problem.

**Notes:**

- If you establish your MacBook connects just fine, return to your usual Wi-Fi network and skip to option 5 below (re using Wireless Diagnostics).
- If you establish it's a problem with your MacBook, or you can't test on another Wi-Fi network for a while, then proceed with the following options instead.
- Of course, there is nothing stopping you from trying all options anyway, as it's also possible to be some sort of conflict between your MacBook and usual Wi-Fi network.

**2. Remove your Wi-Fi service**

You can totally remove your Wi-Fi service, restart, and add your Wi-Fi service back.

To do this:

1. Go to Apple > System Preferences > Network
2. Select the Wi-Fi service on the left-hand side
3. Click on the cog icon at bottom-left and select Make Service Inactive
4. Now delete the service by clicking on the minus sign (i.e. the <kbd>-</kbd> button) at left of the cog
5. Click on the <kbd>Apply</kbd> button
6. Exit Network preferences
7. Restart your MacBook
8. Go to Apple > System Preferences > Network
9. Click on the plus sign (i.e. the <kbd>+</kbd> button) at left of the cog
10. In the pop-up window, ensure that Wi-Fi is selected from the drop-down menu
11. Click on the <kbd>Create</kbd> button
12. Make sure Wi-Fi is on and connected (it should remember your previous settings, but if not just re-add your Wi-Fi network again)

Let me know if this resolves the issue.

**3. Boot into Safe Mode**

If removing the Wi-Fi service etc didn't work, let's try booting your MacBook into Safe Mode:

1. Fully shut down your MacBook
2. Restart your MacBook
3. Immediately press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and **keep it down**
4. Let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window (NOTE: If you 
   have FileVault enabled you may need to log in twice).
5. Test to see what happens
6. Exit Safe Mode by restarting your MacBook as normal
7. Test again to see what happens

Note, booting into Safe Mode will take longer than usual.

**4. Test your hardware**

You don't specify your model of MacBook, so it's not clear whether you need to use Apple Hardware Test or Apple Diagnostics to do this. If your MacBook was introduced:

- **before** June 2013, it uses Apple Hardware Test. [Follow these steps](https://support.apple.com/HT201257).
- **after** June 2013, it uses Apple Diagnostics. [Follow these steps](https://support.apple.com/HT202731).

**5. Run Wireless Diagnostics**

You can use [Wireless Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchlf4de377f/mac) to analyse your Wi-Fi network. Follow these steps:

1. Close any apps you have running
2. Connect to the Wi-Fi network
3. Hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key and go to the Wi-Fi status menu and select Open Wireless Diagnostics
4. Enter your administrator name and password
5. Now follow the steps to see whether any problems are found.

---

Regardless of which options you try (or whether you try all of them) let me know how you go. If the above steps don't resolve the issue, then we've still narrowed down the possibilities and can go on from there.

Comment: Thanks! I probably won’t be able to do this til tomorrow, but I’ll keep you posted.

Comment: After running Apple Diagnostics it reported no issues. I restarted and ran the OS as regularly and the wifi was back on and working correctly. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

For my case which it made me little disappointed because my upload file process would keep getting disconnected (the file would take 5 hours to upload but it would get disconnect after 3 hours).
The solution was to disable energy saving by setting it to never.

[image]

[image]